# Hairline borders between my tables in Gmail Android App (Android 5-6)

Tags: android, email, gmail, email-templates

I am going crazy trying to figure out why this happening.  I have hairline borders appearing between my tables in my Gmail App on Android 5-6 on a email template i'm working on for a client. This doesnt appear in any other client but the gmail app. The weird thing is, when I zoom in the hairlines disappear on a specific zoom level.

The hairlines are very light but you can see them in the screenshot

[image]

I have border-collapse:collapse on all tables with cellpadding, cellspacing, border and border-spacing all set to 0.

Any assistance or input anyone could have would be really appreciated.

Comment: try putting the outer table background color to white and if doesnt work then all td's border and background color to white. This used to happen in iOS when you use different background colors.

Comment: Thank you! @syfer the white border and background on td's did the job!

Comment: I have placed it as an answer so you can select it and it can be used for anyone who sees this post in future :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try putting the outer table background color to white and if doesnt work then all td's border and background color to white. This used to happen in iOS when you use different background colors.